# How do I resume execution after using ud2 with vectored exception handling?

Tags: c++, exception, winapi, error-handling, x86-64

I want to trigger an exception using `ud2`, record information about the exception, then continue execution from there. Right now my code is stuck in an infinite loop of repeatedly reexecuting `ud2`

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void resumeFromUD2()
{
    PVOID handler = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, [](struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo)->LONG
        {
            std::cout << "vectored exception handled\n";
            std::cout << "exception code: " << std::hex << ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode << std::dec << "\n";
            return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
        });
    int testValue = 0;

    testValue++;
    __ud2();
    testValue++;

    //should be 2
    std::cout << "testValue: " << testValue << '\n';
    RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(handler);
}
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I messed with this, but you probably need to modify the thread context to move the instruction pointer past the offending statement before resuming.

Comment: In case it's not obvious why that's happening, `ud2` produces a `#UD` fault, which like a `#PF` happens with the saved RIP pointing at the faulting instruction.  Unlike an `int 0x80` instruction where the saved RIP points after the trapping instruction.  So to skip an instruction, you'd have to know the instruction length.  For UD2 specifically, with no prefixes that's 2 bytes.

Comment: As others have mentioned you'd have to read the 2 bytes at RIP (instruction pointer) to determine if it is a UD2 instruction and advance RIP by 2 bytes. The _EXCEPTION_POINTERS structure has a  PCONTEXT (pointer to a context) member. A CONTEXT structure has an `Rip` member. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-exception_pointers and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-context

Comment: @MichaelPetch how do I set the instruction pointer?

Comment: You can directly modify `Rip` in `ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Rip` (add 2 to it)  . When the exception returns back to CS:RIP it will return to that new RIP. Adding 2 to it would advance over the UD2 instruction to the following instruction which should avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: @MichaelPetch put this in an answer and I will accept it

Comment: If it worked, you can self answer your question. Be my guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `ud2` instruction doesn't increment the instruction pointer, meaning that it triggers the exception, then resumes right where it left off, executing `ud2` again and triggering the exception again.

You can fix this by manually moving the instruction pointer forward by two bytes (the size of the `ud2` instruction), thus resuming execution.

This can be done by modifying the instruction pointer via the _EXCEPTION_POINTERS structure that gets passed to the exception handler.

That code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void resumeFromUD2()
{
    PVOID handler = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, [](struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo)->LONG
        {
            ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Rip += 2;
            std::cout << "vectored exception handled\n";
            std::cout << "exception code: " << std::hex << ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode << std::dec << "\n";
            return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
        });
    int testValue = 0;

    testValue++;
    __ud2();
    testValue++;

    //should be 2
    std::cout << "testValue: " << testValue << '\n';
    RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(handler);
}
```